# PowerShell Help System

Tags: powershell

So there is two ways of using help in PoSH, for advanced functions you can use comment based help, my question is when you use comment based help does it produce MAML? As for native cmdlets is a help XML file MAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment based help is interpreted by Get-Help, it doesn't produce MAML files. You can use the Cmdlet Help  Editor to create MAML files for snap-ins or modules. You can find it on CodePlex:

http://cmdlethelpeditor.codeplex.com/